# angular 2 server rendering with java back-end

Tags: java, angular, angular2-universal

I use angular 2 with a java back-end (tomcat).
I am trying to implements server-side rendering in my POC.
I was wondering if angular universal could help me (on client side).
I apologize in advance, I am quite new to angular AND nodejs.

In order to understand server side rendering with universal, I take a look at https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/tree/master and https://github.com/alexpods/angular2-universal-starter.

First of all, I am wondering if the behaviour I observe for those project is normal:

For the first one, the preboot don't seem to work, (I put the preboot flag to true in main.node.ts) : if I type something in the input field, it is removed when angular loads...

For the second one, I wonder if the server rendering really work, because even if I add throttling in my chrome options, the loading time is long, and the page appear after that (as if it was client rendered after all assets downloads)

Also I have to say my POC may be naive and simple for the moment, but it's hard for me to understand the entry points of those project, mine is simple :

html :

```
<script src="/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

systemjs :

```
...
  var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
...
```

main.ts (compiled in js)

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Maybe I miss some nodejs understandings.

Finaly can someone explain what are the exact differences between the server rendred and client rendered version of a page?

Thanks a lot!